# Load Facebook Like (or similar) scripts once

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-like

Is there any method to have the buttons from these plugins twice in a page, but load their scripts only once?

Plugins such as: Facebook Like, Tweet this, G+ this.

Example:
In a blog post underneath the title I have: Tweet this, G+ and Facebook Like. On the left side of this post there is a fixed bar with the same buttons: Facebook, Tweet and Google.

The scripts are loaded twice for each button rendering.

Just curious if any method exists/done so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scripts are exactly the same then yes they will get loaded twice, but one of them will be loaded from the browsers cache.  There is not much to worry about here.

Chances are the user already has these scripts in their browsers cache even before visiting your site.  We see likes and +1's and tweets and all-sorts **every where** today.  I would say its pretty safe to assume that the average user would have these common scripts cached locally.